# How to compile c++ code at run time in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, runtime, wrapper

I want to compile some c++ code to a dll at runtime using c#. Is that possible? And how do I proceed? Is it possible to simply translate the c++ code to c#? I am new to c++ and do not know if it is even possible. The dll is used in an other application, thus the input and output for the dll is fixed and can not be changed.

I have been looking at cppcodeprovider, however, I does not seem to work.

Would it be possible to build a c++ wrapper for c#?

Here is the c++ code that I want to compile at runtime:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NINT(a) ((a) >= 0.0 ? (int)((a)+0.5) : (int)((a)-0.5))

extern "C"    //avoid mangled names

{ void __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl cDISCON(float *avrSwap, int *aviFail, char *accInfile, char *avcOutname, char *avcMsg);

}

//Main DLL routine

void __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl cDISCON(float *avrSwap, int *aviFail, char *accInfile, char *avcOutname, char *avcMsg)
{      
    char Message[257], InFile[257], OutName[1025];
    float rTime, rMeasuredSpeed, rMeasuredPitch;
    int iStatus, iFirstLog;
    static float rPitchDemand;

    //Take local copies of strings

    memcpy(InFile,accInfile, NINT(avrSwap[49]));
    InFile[NINT(avrSwap[49])+1] = '\0';
    memcpy(OutName,avcOutname, NINT(avrSwap[50]));
    OutName[NINT(avrSwap[50])+1] = '\0';

    //Set message to blank
    memset(Message,' ',257);

    //Set constants
    SetParams(avrSwap);

    //Load variables from Bladed (See Appendix A)
    iStatus = NINT (avrSwap[0]);

    rTime = avrSwap[1];
    rMeasuredPitch = avrSwap[3];
    rMeasuredSpeed = avrSwap[19];

    //Read any External Controller Parameters specified in the User Interface

    if (iStatus == 0) 
    {
        *aviFail = ReadData(InFile, Message);  //User to supply this routine
        rPitchDemand = rMeasuredPitch;         //Initialise
    }

    //Set return values using previous demand if a sample delay is required
    avrSwap[44] = rPitchDemand;

    //Main calculation   //User to supply calcs routine
    if (iStatus >= 0 && *aviFail >= 0) 
        *aviFail = calcs(iStatus, rMeasuredSpeed, rMeasuredPitch, &rPitchDemand, OutName, Message);      

    //Logging output - example
    avrSwap[64] = 2;           //No of outputs

    iFirstLog = NINT(avrSwap[62])-1;         //Address of first output
    strcpy(OutName, "Speed:A/T;Pitch:A");           //Names and units
    avrSwap[iFirstLog] = rMeasuredSpeed;            //First Value
    avrSwap[iFirstLog+1] = rMeasuredPitch;   //Second value

    //Return strings
    memcpy(avcOutname,OutName, NINT(avrSwap[63]));

    memcpy(avcMsg,Message,MIN(256,NINT(avrSwap[48])));

    return;

}
```

Comment: `Is it possible to simply translate the c++ code to c#?` No, don't even bother. You would lose accuracy, and the languages are different. You could port it yourself, but not automaticly.

Comment: The answer to each of the questions is yes, but you really need to clarify what you want to achieve OR learn. Options you've listed require completely different answers.

Comment: @gunr2171 - it is not *practical* in most cases to automatically translate C++ to C#, but theoretically possible :).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, true, but have fun with converting pointers. The other big thing is c++ was made for speed, where c# is more for "usability", so you lose that aspect.

Comment: If you are just trying to compile code programmatically, then use command line. For c#, you would call `msbuild.exe` with your project file. You need to find what the c++ equivalent is. You then might be able to use that in an already-running c# program.

Comment: have you tried pInvoke?

Comment: @yossico Maybe I am confused but pInvoke is used for already compiled dll's? I want to compile some c++ code at runtime. The c++ code change at each run.

Comment: @gunr2171 How do I translate this to c#?: void __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl cDISCON::SayThis(float *avrSwap, int *aviFail, char *accInfile, char *avcOutname, char *avcMsg)